# PHP while loop contents into email with PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have this while lop which gives me all users that have logged in today:

```
<?php while ($users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <p><?php echo $users['lastLogIn'];?> - <?php  echo $users['userName']; ?></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to email these results once a day so also have a send mail function:

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject){                       
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;                  
$mail->SMTPSecure = "";                 
$mail->Host       = "10.10.10.10";      
$mail->Port       = 25;            
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Username="Anonymous";  
$mail->Password="Anonymous";            
$mail->SetFrom('noreply@email.co.uk','Hello');
$mail->AddReplyTo("noreply@email.co.uk","Hello");
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
}
```

but I need to know how I cant print the results of the query into the email this is what I have but not sure where to go next...

```
$email = ("email@email.co.uk");
$message= "        
    Hello, $email
   <br /><br />
   Please find a list of users below who logged in today : 
   <br /><br />
   I want the while loop content here";
$subject = "Daile User Log";

send_mail($email,$message,$subject);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, instead of sending the strings your create to a requesting browser by using an `echo` statement inside the loop you concatenate them to a variable which you can then use later on the fill your message content:

```
<?php 
$listOfUsers = '';
while ($user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $listOfUsers .= sprintf("%s - %s\n", $user['lastLogIn'], $user['userName']);
}

$message = <<<EOT
Hello ${email}, 
please find a list of users below who logged in today : 

${listOfUsers}
EOT;
```

Note: I removed the html markup from the message content, since it only makes things more complex.

Comment: How would i add a line break after each line to make it more easily readable in the email?

Comment: There are line breaks in the message, you can see the `"\n"` I add. It might be that some non standard conform email client insists on MS-Windows style line breaks, but that is something you can't really pre-guess when sending the message, so there is little sense in using `"\r\n"` instead. More likely you are still sending html formatted email messages (why ever...). In that case do as you did in your own example and add html style line wrape (`<br>`) to your messages.